# Converting to clausal form for using Resolution on formulas with free variables

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The resolution rule in first order logic is used with FOL sentences (formulas without free variables). Is it possible to do Resolution on general FOL formulas? If so, how does the conversion to clausal form should be done? The conversion is important because for sentences, we eliminate existential quantifiers and move universal quantifiers outside, and drop them. So the resulting clausal form implicitly universally quantified. If we have free variables, this produces problems with this universally quantification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "basic" use of [Resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) is to show that a formula $\mathcal A$ is *valid*.

The method applies to $\mathcal B := \lnot \mathcal A$ trying to derive the *empty clause* : $\square$.

If so, we conclude that $\mathcal B$ is **not** *satisfiable*, and thus that $\mathcal A$ is *valid*.

---

Having said that, what is the definition of *valid* for an *open* FOL formula, i.e. a formula with free occurrences of variables ?

See Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1447145577) (5th ed - 2013), page 67 :

> **Definition 3.4.3** : Let $FV(\varphi) = \{ z_1,\ldots, z_k \}$, then $Cl(\varphi) := ∀z_1 \ldots \forall z_k \varphi$ is the *universal closure* of $\varphi$.
>
> **Definition 3.4.4** : (i) $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi$ iff $\mathfrak A \vDash Cl(\varphi)$,
>
> (ii) $\vDash \varphi$ iff $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi$ for all $\mathfrak A$.

Thus, an *open* formula is valid iff its universal closure is.

Compare with Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122384520) (2nd ed - 2001), page 88 :

> [A formula] $\varphi$ is *valid* iff for every $\mathfrak A$ and every [function] $s : Var \to |\mathfrak A|$, $\mathfrak A$ satisfies $\varphi$ with $s$.

And page 99 :

> A formula $θ$ is valid iff $∀x θ$ is valid.

---

Thus, in order to apply resolution to an open FOL formula $\alpha(x)$, we have to apply the procedure to $\lnot \forall x \alpha(x)$. If this formula is *unsatisfiable*, then $\alpha(x)$ is *valid*.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for late reply. What if we want to use resolution to show that a set of formulas entail another formula ($\Gamma\models \alpha$), and the formula with free variables is in $\Gamma$? In this situation we convert $\Gamma \cup \neg\alpha$ to CNF and then use resolution on that, so the formula with free variable is not negated.

Comment: @LoMaPh - Consider for simplicity $\Gamma$ with only one formula $\gamma$; to show that $\gamma \vDash \alpha$ is to show that $\vDash \gamma \rightarrow \alpha$, i.e that $\gamma \rightarrow \alpha$ is *valid* and this amounts to show that $\gamma \land \lnot \alpha$ is *unsatisfiable*. Thus, we have to apply *resolution* to $\gamma$ and $\lnot \alpha$; if $\gamma$ has free var $x$, we have to consider the *closure* $\forall x \gamma$.